# AWS Glue Cannot read case sensitive table from ORACLE

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I am trying to bring data from Oracle table that is case sensitive to AWS S3 using AWS Glue. Oracle query looks something like below:

```
Select *
from myschema."Employee_Salary"
```

AWS Crawler is able to pull the table metadata, but the Glue job is not pulling the data, and it is giving error as "no table or view exists".

My sample code looks like below:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "orctest4", table_name = "orcl_orcl_Employee_Salary", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("empid", "decimal(10,2)", "empid", "decimal(10,2)"), ("addressdescription", "string", "addressdescription", "string"), ("salary_id", "decimal(10,2)", "salary_id", "decimal(10,2)"), ("salary_amount", "decimal(10,2)", "salary_amount", "decimal(10,2)"), ("manager_id", "decimal(10,0)", "manager_id", "decimal(10,0)")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://test/my_orcle_parquet"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: I don't know much about AWS Glue, but in your code the table is called `orcl_orcl_Employee_Salary`. Does that represent `myschema.Employee_Salary`?

Comment: Have you tried adding the connection to your glue job?

Comment: Can you read other tables in the same Oracle schema that do not have a case sensitive name?